# Gtk+ Serial port event cause responsiveness

Tags: gtk

I am trying to implement event triggered serial port read with Gtk3+.

When the data is received, GUI is getting unresponsive. I think after data receive event the loop does not go to gtk_main(). Sometimes data flow continue from sender device on serial port and GUI turn back to responsive.

So, how to return gtk_main(() loop after receive some bytes from serial?

This is the code that I wrote;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


void signal_handler_IO (int status);   /* definition of signal handler */


volatile int n, fd;
volatile char buf [100];
int connected;
struct termios termAttr;
struct sigaction saio;



void UartInit(){
     fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
     if (fd == -1)
     {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyO1\n");
        exit(1);
     }

     saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
     saio.sa_flags = 0;
     saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
     sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

     fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
     fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
     fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,  O_ASYNC ); /**<<<<<<------This line made it work.**/

     tcgetattr(fd,&termAttr);
     //baudRate = B115200;          /* Not needed */
     cfsetispeed(&termAttr,B115200);
     cfsetospeed(&termAttr,B115200);
     termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
     termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
     termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
     termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
     termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
     termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
     termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
     termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
     tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&termAttr);
     printf("UART1 configured....\n");
     //close(fd);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *main_window, *label, *image, *image_alt;

    GtkWidget *main_box;     /* VBox to hold main_hbox and the controls */
  GtkWidget *controls;     /* HBox to hold the buttons and the slider */

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); //Inititalize GTK
    main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(main_window, 480, 800);
    label = gtk_label_new("deeneme");
    //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);

    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), FALSE); //Hide menu bar

    image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/x/Desktop/downArrow2.png");
    image_alt = gtk_image_new_from_file("/home/x/Desktop/arcelik.png");
    //gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_window), image);

    controls = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), image, FALSE, FALSE, 50);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    main_box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);


    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), controls, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), image_alt, FALSE, FALSE, 0); //altda ki image ekle
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), main_box);


    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window); //Show all widgets


   // gtk_widget_hide(image);


    UartInit(); //Initialize UART

    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), "<span foreground=\"white\" size='300100'>1</span>"); //Set number color and size......1234




    gtk_main(); //Start main loop
    return 0;
}

void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{

  int n = read (fd, &buf, sizeof buf);
  if(n > 1)
  {
    buf[n] = '\0';
    printf("Receive OK %s\n",buf);
  }
}
```